# Windows Forms WorkSpace not showing anything in solution explorer and attach to process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with opening Windows Forms App as a project templates in visual studio 2022.
When i'm opening template Windows Forms App(.Net Framework) i have everything in solution explorer(i mean photo 1) [image: photo 1] but when im choosing template Windows Forms App  i dont have anything in my solution explorer and i have to attach to process instead of debug app and it looks like this [image: photo 2] I supposed that something is wrong with my .net  cause when im using  Windows Forms App(.Net Framework) i have the newest one .net 4.8.1 [image: photo 3]

I was trying to reinstall whole vs 2022 but it didnt work

Comment: you are not opening the .sln file.. in your second screnshot

Comment: yes, but when im opening .sln file it also shows me nothing in solution explorer

Comment: it should not because in your second screenshot, no solution is loaded, and hence the reason why you see attach instead of debug. Try right clicking on your Test and add Project, and select your csproj file

Comment: still when im adding new project and i want to add Windows Forms App it displays nothing(same as photo 2)

Comment: but when im adding new project and clicking on Windows Forms App(.Net Framework) it works propely but only with maximum 4.8.1 .NET

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are saying. Can you edit your question to include step-by-step instructions about how you got to your good and bad situations: 1) Open VS, 2) Choose new project, 3) pick template (specify exactly, including Framework or Core), etc.

Comment: What does your `test.sln` file contain? The screenshots show you opened two different solutions, `WindowsFormsApp227.sln` and `test.sln`. Or, perhaps, you tried to open the `test` folder directly. It's quite possible that `test.sln` has no projects included. An `.sln` file is *only* used to group projects together in Visual Studio. It doesn't define any relations between projects. You can easily have just a `.csproj` file without a Solution file. When you open a folder or a `csproj` file directly in VS, the IDE will display a Solution node as well

Comment: What's why you need to explain how you opened or created `test`. It's definitely not the original solution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the problem was with my dotnet environment variables, cause variables was incorrectly configured.  Deleting from "This PC -> Right click 'Properties' -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables –> System variables –> double click path"-> exactly this variable ->"C:\Program Files (x86 ) \dotnet" solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your dotnet environment variables are configured incorrectly. Here is the situation I reproduced:

.net framework

[image]

.net

[image]

**Then the correct solution to this issue is:**

You can modify the environment variables and find the path "This PC -> Right click 'Properties' -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables –> System variables –> double click path"-> Delete "C:\Program Files (x86 ) \dotnet" and make sure there is "C:\Program Files\dotnet".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Of course, it may also be because "C:\Program Files\dotnet" is not the correct path. This requires you to find the correct installation location of your dotnet and modify it.

Finally, when your dotnet environment variables are configured correctly, you will find that everything is normal when you re-create a .net program.